# Work done by an ideal gas in any arbitrary container

Tags: thermodynamics

In a container of any arbitrary shape, an ideal gas is trapped and caused to expand. The ideal gas is well trapped that there is zero mass flow between the inside of the container and the outside. How to show that the work done by the gas on the surrounding environment is given by $\int pdV$? $p$ is the pressure of the ideal gas inside the container and $V$ is the volume of the gas.

ps: I hope this is not considered a stupid question, but I don't know how to prove this formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let dA represent a differential element of surface area between the gas and its surroundings, and let $\mathbf{n}$ represent a unit outwardly-directed normal from the gas to the surroundings across this surface.  Since the pressure force that a gas exerts on a surface is always normal to the surface, the differential force acting on this differential element of surface area at time t during the volume change is equal to $p\mathbf{n}(dA)$.  Let $d\mathbf{s}=\mathbf{v}dt$ represent the differential displacement of the surface area element during time interval dt.  The rate at which the gas does work on the differential element of surface during the time interval dt is $$p\mathbf{n}(dA)\centerdot \frac{d\mathbf{s}}{dt}=p(\mathbf{n}\centerdot\mathbf{v})dA $$If we integrate this equation over the entire surface enclosing the gas, we obtain the rate at which the gas does work on its surroundings:
$$\frac{dW}{dt}=\int_A{p(\mathbf{n}\centerdot\mathbf{v})dA }=p\int_A{(\mathbf{n}\centerdot\mathbf{v})dA }$$Since only the normal component of velocity contributes to the rate of change of volume of the enclosing surface, the integral in the above equation represents the rate of change of volume enclosing the gas.  Thus, $$\frac{dW}{dt}=p\frac{dV}{dt}$$

Comment: This is amazing! I am learning introductory thermodynamics in college and all these differentials and integrals really confuse me!

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  The math is supposed to be incidental (at least in my opinion) to learning and applying science disciplines.